# Does SP2013 Conent Deployment Destination URL Need to be Default Alternate Access Mapping (AMM)

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, content-deployment

We have an internet facing SharePoint 2013 Web Application. We are using Content Deployment job to push content to the Intenet facing farm.

We are about to go live and need to change the default AAM to the production URL. We are going to move the temp url to the Custom AMM.

Will this have any impact on the Content Deployment Job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the Path settings of the Content Deployment that address Should be in default zone, but once everything setup then you can move it to custom zone.

We have our AAM URL in the Custom Zone as of now.